# 私のgulpの実行速度はなぜこんなにも遅いのか

Tags: gulp

gulp:var.4
gulp-pug:var.5
実行するのに67sかかっています

[image: gulpでpugをcompile]

[image: ローカル環境での実行]

Comment: Onedriveの文字が見えますが、もしかしてネットワーク上のストレージとフォルダ同期をしていますか？もしローカルの同期していないフォルダで同様の処理をすると同じスピードになりますか？

Comment: スクリーンショットには 67ms と書かれている箇所がありますが、これとは別に 67s かかった、というのを質問者さん自身が測定したという認識で良いでしょうか？

Comment: >>スクリーンショットには 67ms と書かれている箇所がありますが　すみませんtypoです

Comment: >> もしローカルの同期していないフォルダで同様の処理をすると同じスピードになりますか？ 画像を追加しておきました なんか遅くなりました。

Comment: 個人的な感覚ですが、 67ms の実行速度はそれほど遅いとは感じません。どのような理由で遅いと考えたのでしょうか？

Comment: （実行速度を書いておいてなんですが）enterを押下してからfinishedの表示まで体感で5秒ほどでした